# Powershell How to query multiple classes and write in to SQL Table

Tags: sql, powershell, insert, wmi

Not knowing Powershell very well and indeed sql it's taken me all week to piece together a script thatkind of works but I need help expanding on it.  It works for retrieving more than 1 value from the same class and inserts the values.  What I need to do is to be able to retrieve values from other classes and insert the result in to the appropriate column.  Any help / advice would be so appreciated.

```
$servernames = Get-WmiObject -computername Anycompname -class win32_ComputerSystem |     Select Name, Manufacturer

# Open Connection
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connectionString = "Server=;Database=;user=;pwd=;"
$conn.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$conn.Open()

# Create the Command object to execute the queries
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text

# Write Data
foreach ($servername in $servernames)
{
# Compose Query for this $servername - watch the single quotes for string values!!
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.U_Server (ServerName, OSVersion) VALUES ('" +        $servername.Name + "', '" + $servername.Manufacturer + "')"

# Uncomment next line to display query for checking
$query 

# Setup Command
$cmd.CommandText = $query

# Execute Command to insert data for this $drive
$result = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
}

# Tidy Up 
$conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the other WMI object(s) in the foreach loop and keep adding to your insert string as needed.

```
foreach ($servername in $servernames)
{
##  Get other WMI info as needed here.
$os = Get-WmiObject -class win32_operatingsystem –computername $servername.Name
$processors = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -computername $servername.Name

# Compose Query for this $servername 
$query = "Insert Into dbo.U_Server (ServerName, OSVersion, OSName, OSServicePack) Values 
('$($servername.Name)', '$($servername.Manufacurer)', ‘$($os.Caption)’, ‘$($os.ServicePackMajorVersion)’ )"

##  The rest of your foreach loop follows

}  ##  End of foreach
```

Comment: Thanks a million Bruce.  I will try this out and report back

Comment: Hey Bruce - when expanding the foreach loop how should it look?    # Write Data
foreach ($servername in $servernames),($OS in $OS)

or  foreach ($servername in $servernames) | ($OS in $OS)

Thanks in advance.  Really, really new to this:-)

Comment: I expanded my answer to show where/how to get added WMI information.

Comment: Thanks Bruce - Will try this out asap.

Comment: Cheers Bruce.  Got my head round it and it works.  Thanks again.  Sorry for delay in trying this out.