# Use Powershell to insert data into multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to insert data collected from VMware vCenter into a database using Powershell and SQL Server.

This is what I have for now:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Computer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $conn

$val = 0
$clusterinf = foreach($cluster in Get-Cluster){
$esx = $cluster | Get-VMHost
$ds = Get-Datastore -VMHost $esx | where {$_.Type -eq "VMFS"}

$cluster | Select @{N="VCname";E={$cluster.Uid.Split(':@')[1]}},
    @{N="DCname";E={(Get-Datacenter -Cluster $cluster).Name}},
    @{N="Clustername";E={$cluster.Name}},        
    @{N="TotalPhysicalMemory";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property MemoryTotalMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="TotalUsedMemory";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property MemoryUsageMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="AvailableMemroy";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.MemoryTotalMB - $_.MemoryUsageMB} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="TotalCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property CpuTotalMhz -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="TotalUsedCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property CpuUsageMhz -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="AvailableCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.CpuTotalMhz - $_.CpuUsageMhz} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="TotalDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | where {$_.Type -eq "VMFS"} | Measure-Object -Property CapacityMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="ConfiguredDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.CapacityMB - $_.FreeSpaceMB} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="AvailableDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | Measure-Object -Property FreeSpaceMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
    @{N="Total Configured Memory GB For Powered on VMs";E={[Math]::Round(($_ | Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | %{$_.MemoryMB} | Measure-Object -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum)/1KB) }}

$cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Clusterinfo (VCname) VALUES('{$val}')" -f $clusterinf.VCname
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   
$val++     

}
$conn.close()
```

And this is working as intended i believe. Now my question is, how do I continue with the next column? So that I can add `DCname`, `Clustername`, `TotalPhysicalMemory` and so on?

I have been trying with this insert statement:

```
$cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Clusterinfo (VCname, DCname, CLustername) VALUES('$($clusterinf.VCname)','$($clusterinf.DCname)','$($clusterinf.Clustername)')"
```

But its not realy giving the wanted result, as it will insert every `VCname`, `DCname` and so on, into one row, and not into different rows.

I have been looking at this question: [Powershell How to query multiple classes and write in to SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144768/powershell-how-to-query-multiple-classes-and-write-in-to-sql-table)

But I can't seem to get my head around a solution to my own question.

Anybody got an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$clusterinf` needs to be the object with the data of the current cluster, not the result of the entire foreach-loop.

I would try something like this:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Computer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $conn

foreach($cluster in (Get-Cluster)){

    $esx = $cluster | Get-VMHost
    $ds = Get-Datastore -VMHost $esx | where {$_.Type -eq "VMFS"}

    $clusterinf = $cluster | Select @{N="VCname";E={$cluster.Uid.Split(':@')[1]}},
        @{N="DCname";E={(Get-Datacenter -Cluster $cluster).Name}},
        @{N="Clustername";E={$cluster.Name}},        
        @{N="TotalPhysicalMemory";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property MemoryTotalMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="TotalUsedMemory";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property MemoryUsageMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="AvailableMemroy";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.MemoryTotalMB - $_.MemoryUsageMB} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="TotalCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property CpuTotalMhz -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="TotalUsedCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -Property CpuUsageMhz -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="AvailableCPU";E={[Math]::Round(($esx | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.CpuTotalMhz - $_.CpuUsageMhz} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="TotalDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | where {$_.Type -eq "VMFS"} | Measure-Object -Property CapacityMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="ConfiguredDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | Measure-Object -InputObject {$_.CapacityMB - $_.FreeSpaceMB} -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="AvailableDiskSpace";E={[Math]::Round(($ds | Measure-Object -Property FreeSpaceMB -Sum).Sum /1KB)}},
        @{N="Total Configured Memory GB For Powered on VMs";E={[Math]::Round(($_ | Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | %{$_.MemoryMB} | Measure-Object -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum)/1KB) } }

    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Clusterinfo (VCname, Clustername, TotalPhysicalMemory, TotalUsedMemory, AvailableMemroy, TotalCPU, TotalUsedCPU, AvailableCPU, TotalDiskSpace, ConfiguredDiskSpace, AvailableDiskSpace) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')" -f $clusterinf.VCname, $clusterinf.Clustername, $clusterinf.TotalPhysicalMemory, $clusterinf.TotalUsedMemory, $clusterinf.AvailableMemroy, $clusterinf.TotalCPU, $clusterinf.TotalUsedCPU, $clusterinf.AvailableCPU, $clusterinf.TotalDiskSpace, $clusterinf.ConfiguredDiskSpace, $clusterinf.AvailableDiskSpace
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$conn.close()
```

As a side note, you should replace commandtext with values with parameters. It's less prone to SQL injection and is alot cleaner in my opinon. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Frode F, thank you very much. Its working perfect. I actually did try to do it that way, before with my script, but in the database I only got "System.Object[]" inserted, instead of the values. So I guess by moving $clusterinf inside the foreach loop, its working as intented. Guess I simply could not see that. Again, thanks a million for pointing that out to me. And also, thank you for the side note, i will look into it. Have a great evening.